# How do I refer to defined objects using the reshape function in R?

Tags: r, reshape

I'm unable to get the reshape function ( stats::reshape ) to accept a reference to a defined character vector in one of its arguments. I don't know if this reflects wrong syntax on my part, a limitation of the function, or a more general issue related to how R itself operates.

I am using reshape to change data from wide to long format. I have a dataset with many repeated measures that are sorted appropriately for reshape (x.1, x.2, x.3, y.1, y.2, y.3, etc). I've defined a variable `firstlastmeasure` that contains the index to the first and last column of repeated measures data that needs to be processed by reshape (this is to prevent having to change the index every time columns are added or removed from the original data).

This is how it's defined (in a convoluted way):

```
temp0 <- subset(p, select=nameoffirstcolumn:nameoflastcolumn)
lastmeasname = names(temp0[ncol(temp0)])
firstmeasname = names(temp0[1])
firstmeasindex = grep(firstmesname,colnames(p))
lastmeasindex = grep(lastmesname,colnames(p))
firstlastmeasure <- paste(firstmesindex,lastmesindex,sep=":")
```

I'm using this variable as an argument to reshape's `varying` parameter, like so:

```
reshape(dataset, direction = "long", varying = firstlastmeasure)
```

Reshape always returns:

> "Error in guess(varying) : failed to guess time-varying variables from their names".

Using the numerical index explicitly (i.e. `varying = 6:34`) works fine.

Comment: Can you make your example reproducible? Share just enough data to illustrate the problem? Also, there is no function named `reshape` in the `reshape2` package. `reshape2` has `melt`, `cast`, `dcast`, and `recast` as it's workhorse function. I assume you're using the built-in `stats::reshape`.

Comment: Please provide the code for defining `firstlastmeasure`.

Comment: It also doesn't sound like you are using the `varying` parameter correctly, from `?stats::reshape`, `varying` is described as "names [or indexes] of sets of variables in the wide format that correspond to single variables in long format." I don't get that from your description of `firstlastmeasure`. Instead of "index to the first and last column of repeated measures", could you do `index_to_first:index_to_last`?

Comment: Sorry this is actually the built in reshape function, I've fixed the question.

Comment: @Gregor  That actually worked, thanks! So in terms of my defined objects it was: varying=firstmeasindex:lastmeasindex that worked

Comment: @Eldur the reason `firstlastmeasure <- paste(firstmesindex,lastmesindex,sep=":")` doesn't work is that it's a character string, not a sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`paste` creates a string, if you look at `firstlastmeasure` it will be something like `"6:34"`. If you look at `6:34` it will be a vector `6 7 8 9 ... 34`. You need to define the vector, not paste together a string. (Note that `subset` does a bit of special processing to make `:` work with column names.)

If I'm interepreting your code correctly, `temp0` has all the column you want, so you could just do

```
firstlastmeasure = names(temp0)
```

and be done with it. A little more complicated, you could keep you `grep` code and just not use `paste`:

```
firstlastmeasure = firstmeasindex:lastmeasindex
```

Since you are inputting names, the `subset` is unnecessary. Simplest of all would be to skip `temp0` and do

```
firstlastmeasure = grep(nameoffirstcolumn, names(p)):grep(nameoflastcolumn, names(p))
```